# Automatically add spaces arround binary operators (using regexp matching whit emacs)

Tags: regex, emacs, whitespace

I want match all binary operators in my code and make sure they are surrounded by spaces (for coding style purpose). Spaces have to be added if needed.

I am using emacs and I am confident in the fact that it is possible using `replace-regexp` or something similar.

Binary operators are considered for C language only. And for now I have some not exhaustive cases study:

### Standard cases

`a=b` will become `a = b`

`a+=b` will become `a += b`

`a-=b` etc...

`a*=b`

`a/=b`

### Left token glued

`a= b` will become `a = b`

`a+= b` will become `a += b`

etc...

### Right token glued

`a =b` will become `a = b`

`a +=b` will become `a += b`

etc...

### Control cases

`a = b` or `a += b` etc... have NOT to be change (we don't want to add some more spaces)

## First try

I try to match this regular expression : `[^ ]\\+?\\-?\\*?\\/?=[^ ]` meaning the `=` symbol with any character other than space at it's right and any arithmetic operator (`+*-/`), once or zero times (using `?`) preceded by any other character than space at it's left.
I am here because these dose not work, at least with `re-building` emacs function. Matches are wrong. Is someone have any idea to help ?

P.S : I focus on those regexp because `+`, `*` and `-` symbols are special character in regexp. But I hope being able to apply this function to all C binary operators in the future.

P.P.S : I know there will be a problem with `*` characters and pointers but I keep it for later...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/davidshepherd7/electric-operator

seems worth a try. Tell which major-mode you are using maybe.

Comment: I didn't test it yet but seems exactly the thing that I'm looking for ! many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Regexps are not applicable for code indenting because they will match everything, including substrings in string constants, in comments etc. You may create your own style for indenting or probably some builtin style will fit your needs: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentingC

Comment: So you just say it is impossible that way ? I believe I can exclude tabs and or end of line from match ... no ?

Comment: You will also need to exclude matching from pieces of code like this:

Comment: Sorry,

You will also need to exclude matching from pieces of code like this:  

    /* my *= beautiful *= comment */
    char *s = "MMM += my great string =+ MMM";

After adding all such exclusions you will realize that you created your own parser of C syntax. But that is already already done in Emacs modules which are used by indenting commands.  

Parser of C syntax contains huge number of rules (at lexer and grammar levels) and it's impossible to implement it just with regexps.

Comment: Well, that was what I expected when I try this. But I don't find any package that do this for me in emacs (yet).